# On which partition should I install Ubuntu or Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-13.04

Currently I am using Windows 8 Pro on my system. I want to use Ubuntu or Kubuntu with windows. I tried to install both of it. During installation, when I reached the page to select the partition to install Ubuntu or Kubuntu I was confused about which partition to choose. I will provide my screenshot below. Please tell me which one should  I choose. Also there are 2 more partitions shown in the partition list. I don't know where it came from. My system's hard disk has only 2 partitions.

[image: This is the screen shot]

As I was suggested, I created a new partition on sda4 and tried to install Ubuntu 13.04. The same old problem is still there. Only 4 partitions are showing still. [image: This is the screen shot]

Can I delete sda1 or sda2 partitions ? If possible, how ?

What I also noted is that the Install alongside Windows option is not showing too. How can I solve these issues and install Ubuntu successfully ?

Comment: If you delete either sda1 or sda2 you will make Windows unbootable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1Mb partition is BIOS boot partition (for booting from GPT), needed to boot modern computers (hidden in windows)

104Mb partition is windows boot (also hidden)

sda3 is drive C:

sda4 is second windows partition

To install *buntu you need modern distribution such as 12.04 - 13.10. You need to create one or more new partitions to install, so unallocated space is needed. You must to resize second partition (using windows tools to prevent data loss) to get free space. Then create new partition for / mounting.

Comment: Which partition should I resize to create the new partition, drive C or the other ?

Comment: @TomJ drive D. if it has no data - you can remove it and recreate with smaller size

Comment: @TomJ note about installing ubuntu of UEFI and GPT. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: The 1MiB partition is almost certainly *not* an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is needed to boot in EFI mode. It *might* be a [BIOS Boot Partition,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition) which GRUB uses to boot from GPT disks in BIOS mode, but I'm doubtful of that. I suspect it's actually a BIOS-booting MBR disk. That said, you're right that resizing partitions will be necessary and that installing the 9.10 shown in the screen shot is a bad move -- it's just too old for today.

Comment: @RodSmith Ok. I will try Ubuntu 13.04 then.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 reached end-of-life status a month ago (January 27, 2014). I recommend either the long-term support (LTS) 12.04, which will be good through April 2017, or the latest non-LTS version, 13.10, which will be supported through July 2014. The next LTS release, 14.04, will be out in April of this year. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for release and support schedules for Ubuntu.

Comment: @RodSmith, as I know Windows 8 needs GPT. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @TomJ 13.04 is good for first steps, you will see actual versions.

Comment: Windows 8 does ***not*** need GPT -- at least, not unconditionally. Windows ties boot mode to partition table type: If the computer boots in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, Windows requires MBR on the boot disk; if the computer boots in EFI/UEFI mode, Windows requires GPT on the boot disk. In either case, Windows can use either type of partition table for non-boot (data-only) disks. Although new computers that ship with Windows 8 almost always use EFI/GPT, users can install to older (or even new) computers and use BIOS/MBR.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question and answer on this site's sister site:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: This really should be a comment.